# How to make a closed search in Google Docs?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a document where I need to find a text or word, each time i run a function the selection has to go to next if a word or text is found. If it is at the end it should take me to top in a circular way just like find option in notepad.

Is there a way to do it?

I know about `findText(searchPattern, from)` but I do not understand how to use it.

Comment: Where is the question? This is formatted almost like a request, which is not the nature of this community. If you have tried to do something, it is not working, and you have tried to fix/debug it. Post your code, any errors you are receiving, and information on what you have tried.

Comment: You can simply use Javascript substring function, can you include your document and its format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several wrappers and classes in the DocumentApp. They help to work with the contents of the file.

- [Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)
- [Class RangeElement](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/range-element)
- [Class RangeBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/range-builder)

It is necessary to understand carefully what they are responsible. In your case the code below should be work fine:

```
function myFunctionDoc() {

    // sets the search pattern
    var searchPattern = '29';

    // works with current document 
    var document = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();

    // detects selection
    var selection = document.getSelection();

    if (!selection) {
        if (!document.getCursor()) return;
        selection = document.setSelection(document.newRange().addElement(document.getCursor().getElement()).build()).getSelection();
    }
    selection = selection.getRangeElements()[0];

    // searches
    var currentDocument = findNext(document, searchPattern, selection, function(rangeElement) {
        // This is the callback body
        var doc = this;
        var rangeBuilder = doc.newRange();
        if (rangeElement) {
            rangeBuilder.addElement(rangeElement.getElement());
        } else {
            rangeBuilder.addElement(doc.getBody().asText(), 0, 0);
        }
        return doc.setSelection(rangeBuilder.build());
    }.bind(document));

}

// the search engine is implemented on body.findText
function findNext(document, searchPattern, from, callback) {
    var body = document.getBody();
    var rangeElement = body.findText(searchPattern, from);
    return callback(rangeElement);
}
```

It looks for the pattern. If `body.findText` returns `undefined` then it sets on top of the document.

I have a gist about the subject https://gist.github.com/oshliaer/d468759b3587cfb424348fa722765187

Comment: @user3436029 This answer helped you? Usually marked as resolved.